# How to prevent user from changing sort order of JavaFX Table?

Tags: sorting, javafx, tableview

I have a JavaFX table with a default sort specified via FXML

```
<TableView>
  <columns>
    ...
  </columns>
  <sortOrder>
    ...
  </sortOrder>
</TableView>
```

Whenever I add a row I resort the table, which does exactly what I want.

```
myTable.getItems().add(...)
myTable.sort()
```

Now, however, I want to prevent the user from changing the sort order.  How can I do that?

I tried using the `<TableColumn sortable="false" .../>` attribute but if specified on the columns I want to sort by then these columns are no longer sorted.

Comment: Using a [`SortedList`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slaw's suggestion to use the [SortedList](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) works quite nicely.  Here's what needs to be done:

```
@FXML
private TableView<MyThing> tableView;
private ObservableList<MyThing> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    SortedList<MyThing> sortedList = observableList.sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyThing::getDate).thenComparing(MyThing::getTime));
    tableView.setItems(sortedList);
    
public void onAdd(MyThing myThing) {
    observableList.add(myThing);
```

Then just use `<TableColumn sortable="false" .../>` on all columns to prevent the user from changing the sort order.

Comment: Side note: You can also create a `SortedList` via [`ObservableList#sorted(Comparator)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#sorted(java.util.Comparator)).